# Have an error while writing monodb app for the first time

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So, this is the code can any one explain why this code is giving this error.

...
const  { MongoClient } = require('mongodb').Mongoclient;
const assert = require('assert');

```
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

const dbName = 'fruitsdb';

const client = new MongoClient(url, {
useUnifiedTopology: true,
useNewUrlParser: true
});
client.connect(function(err) {
assert.equal(null,err);
console.log("Connected successfully to server");

const db = client.db(dbName);

client.close();
```

});
...

const  { MongoClient } = require('mongodb').Mongoclient;
^

TypeError: Cannot destructure property `MongoClient` of 'undefined' or 'null'.

but this code is not giving error.

...

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const assert = require('assert');

const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

const dbName = 'fruitsdb';

const client = new MongoClient(url, {
useUnifiedTopology: true,
useNewUrlParser: true
});
client.connect(function(err) 
{
assert.equal(null,err);
console.log("Connected successfully to server");

const db = client.db(dbName);

client.close();
```

});

Pls, do explain the code too, I am new to this, and starting out, could you pls explain how the code is working.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this example when you use { "property" } = Object  you select one property that exist in the Object.

```
const data = {
    firstName: "ravi",
    lastName: "kumar",
    friend: {
       firstName: "erfan",
       lastName: "hp",
    }
}


const { firstName } = data; // show ravi

const { firstName } = data.friend; // show erfan
```

we have MongoClient property in require('mongodb')

but we don't have MongoClient property in require('mongodb').MongoClient